# How can i read lines with different format in fortran77

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I need help.
How can I read the below file data and write only the second column using Fortran 77?

```
BASE 1093 Yes Yes Yes   
BASE 1094 Yes Yes Yes   
BASE 1095 Yes Yes Yes   
BASE 1096 Yes Yes Yes   
BASE 1097 Yes Yes Yes    
BASE 6081 Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes                                   
BASE 6082 Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes         
BASE 6083 Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes  
BASE 1098 Yes Yes Yes                                         
BASE 1099 Yes Yes Yes                                  
BASE 6084 Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes         
BASE 6085 Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes        
BASE 6086 Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes Yes
```

my code:

```
DO I=1,Npoint
 READ(2,*) a1,P_LABEL(I),a2,a3,a4,a5
 write(4,*) P_LABEL(I)
 IF (a5.EQ.'Base') THEN
  READ(2,*) P_LABEL(I)
  write(4,*) P_LABEL(I)
 else 
  READ(2,*) a6,a7
  write(*,*) a6,a7
 endif
end do
```

Comment: What have you tried? We don't solve homework for you. Learn to solve a problem.

Comment: Please try explaining what it is you have tried and how it didn't work.

Comment: I made many trials but i failed.
this is one of them.i've just modified the question.

Comment: Welcome on this site. Be sure to read http://stackoverflow.com/tour first.

Comment: Can you comment on your code? What it should do? What it does instead?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are using list-directed input (using `*` as a format) on a file with a varying number of entries.

Generally, this is a bad idea.  List-directed input will skip to the next line (in Fortran parlance, advance to the next record) if it cannot find the number of entries it requires in the current record.

Fortunately, your data file appears to be column-oriented, which makes it easy for Fortran formatted I/O.

So, here is some sample code, which shold be fairly close to Fortran 77. It is not clear to me why people stick to a language standard that belongs in a software museum, but hey... let me just say I don't have a F77 compiler to test this on any more.  Works fine as Fortran 2003, though, and mind the continuation lines, which will very likely be messed up by posting this here.

And, by the way, comparisons are case-sensitive, so "BASE" and "Base" are two different strings.

```
      PROGRAM MAIN
      IMPLICIT CHARACTER*1 (A-Z)
      CHARACTER*4 A
      INTEGER I
      CHARACTER*3 F1, F2, F3, F4, F5,F6

      OPEN(20,FILE="1.dat")
 100  CONTINUE
        READ (20,9000, END=200) A,I,F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6
        PRINT *,A .EQ. "BASE", I, F1.EQ."Yes", F2.EQ."Yes",             &
     &         F3.EQ."Yes", F4.EQ."Yes", F5.EQ."Yes", F6. EQ. "Yes"
      GOTO 100
 200  CONTINUE
 9000 FORMAT (A4,1X,I4,6(1X,A3))
      END
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the second column, you can simply do:

```
 DO I=1,Npoint
     read(2,*)a1, P_LABEL(I)
     write(4,*) P_LABEL(I)
 enddo
```

assuming `a1` is declared a string ( length >=4 ) of course.  The read will automatically ignore the remainder of the line.

Caveat, I don't think this list directed reading of strings was f77 standard,
but then I doubt you really want pure f77 anyway.